# Java Number Tree For Loop

Tags: java, for-loop, numbers

I wrote these nested for loops to display 1 on one line, and 31 on the next, and so on until it get to `97531`. Can someone show me how to reverse it, so that `97531` prints on the first line,then `7531`, and so forth. Basically just flipping the entire output.

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {                  
            int currentNum = 2 * i - 1;                 
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(currentNum);                    
                currentNum = currentNum - 2;
            }               
            System.out.println();
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--) {
    int currentNum = 2 * i - 1;
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(currentNum);
        currentNum = currentNum - 2;
    }
    System.out.println();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
    public class Tester {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--) {                  
                int currentNum = 2 * i - 1;                 
                for (int j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
                    System.out.print(currentNum);                    
                    currentNum = currentNum - 2;
                }               
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```